# How to get Hardwareinformations with C for Windows OS

Tags: c, windows

Could you please tell me how i can get Hardwareinformations from Windows in C?

For example: CPU-ID, CPU-Name, local/network Drives, GPU, Mainboard, Networkcard, ...

I want to get this informations with C and then parse them to Java with JNA/JNI or BridJ.

Answer (score 0):

Use winapi classes and procedures, more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(v=VS.85).aspx
There are also some functions like [getSystemInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381(v=vs.85).aspx)